# Object doesn't support this property or method in IE8: _normalizeServiceName

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, breeze

I'm upgrading my app from .NET 4.0 to 4.5, and upgrading Breeze.js from 1.4.17 to 1.5.4.  Things seem to be working well in IE11 and other browsers, but in IE8 (or in IE11 in IE8 mode) I am getting an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error related to the `_normalizeServiceName` method in this section of code:

```
function updateWithConfig(obj, config) {
  if (config) {
    assertConfig(config)
        .whereParam("serviceName").isOptional()
        .whereParam("adapterName").isString().isOptional()
        .whereParam("uriBuilderName").isString().isOptional()
        .whereParam("hasServerMetadata").isBoolean().isOptional()
        .whereParam("jsonResultsAdapter").isInstanceOf(JsonResultsAdapter).isOptional()
        .whereParam("useJsonp").isBoolean().isOptional()
        .applyAll(obj);
    obj.serviceName = obj.serviceName && DataService._normalizeServiceName(obj.serviceName); // <<< Error here
    obj.adapterInstance = obj.adapterName && __config.getAdapterInstance("dataService", obj.adapterName);
    obj.uriBuilder = obj.uriBuilderName && __config.getAdapterInstance("uriBuilder", obj.uriBuilderName);
  }
  return obj;
}
```

I can see that the `_normalizeServiceName` method is defined right after `updateWithConfig`:

```
ctor._normalizeServiceName = function (serviceName) {
  serviceName = serviceName.trim();
  if (serviceName.substr(-1) !== "/") {
    return serviceName + '/';
  } else {
    return serviceName;
  }
};
```

If I trace through where `DataService` is defined, `ctor` does have the `_normalizeServiceName` method defined when it is returned, but by the time `updateWithConfig` is called it is missing from `DataService`.

The error occurs when I create a new `EntityManager`:

```
this.manager = new breeze.EntityManager(appRoot + "breeze/myapp");
```

The Breeze website seems to say that IE8 is still supported.  I have the ES5 Shim/Sham scripts referenced in a conditional comment:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="/myapp/js/respond.js"></script>
<script src="/myapp/js/es5-shim.js"></script>
<script src="/myapp/js/es5-sham.js"></script>
<script src="/myapp/js/json3.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

So, is IE8 still supported in Breeze?  Did I miss something I need to update in my code when going from Breeze 1.4.x to 1.5.x (the only thing I changed was related to the `Promise` API seeming to change)?  Or is this a bug in Breeze?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not an answer to "does Breeze support IE8", but I thought I would document what I did to get things running again, in case it helps anyone else.

The first issue was that IE8 doesn't like the named constructor functions (if that's even the right terminology) introduced in [this commit to breeze.js](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/commit/a23d257535618d558910724107fb31c73af41057).  To get around that, I added a replace step to my `gulpfile.js` to remove the function names:

```
gulp.task("breeze", function () {
    var js = gulp
        .src(src.bower + "breeze-client/build/breeze.debug.js")
        .pipe(replace(/var ctor = function (\w+)/g, "var ctor = function "))
        .pipe(rename("breeze.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest.js));
    return merge(js);
});
```

Also, since I am using TypeScript, the current typings for Breeze define an `IPromise` interface (changed from `Q.Promise` in [this commit](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/9a5c993fb1b10fca9947ae733d3a90e828162f1d), presumably to support Angular) that uses method names that IE8 doesn't like (catch, finally) and doesn't define the ES3-friendly aliases (fail, fin).  I added my own definitions, and also defined the Q `done()` method:

```
declare module breeze.promises {
    // IE8 (and other ES3 browsers?) don't like .catch and .finally
    // Also define Q's .done method.
    interface IPromise<T> {
        done<U>(): IPromise<U>;
        fail<U>(onRejected: (reason: any) => U): IPromise<U>;
        fail<U>(onRejected: (reason: any) => IPromise<U>): IPromise<U>;
        fin(finallyCallback: () => any): IPromise<T>;
    }
}
```

Finally, I had updated es5-shim to v4.5.7 as part of my upgrade, which seems to break IE8 too, although I have no idea how/why at the moment.  I have no idea what version I was using before (can't find a version number in the .js file) since I had manually copied it in a long time ago.  I had to go all the way back to v4.1.7 to find a version that worked, so presumably it's something in v4.1.8 that breaks IE8.

With all that, things seem to be working in IE8 again!